# Video Could Not Be Composed when using AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am tying to create an app that splices together a number of videos. The issue seems to be that when I combine instructions with `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality` I get an error stating that

> Export failed -> Reason: The video could not be composed., User Info:
>   {
>       NSLocalizedDescription = "Operation Stopped";
>       NSLocalizedFailureReason = "The video could not be composed.";
>       NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-17390 \"(null)\""; }

If I change it to `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` it works ok but the instructions are ignored. Does anyone know what the issue might be using the following code. Im nearly there but this issue is holding me up.

```
AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *track = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                   preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
                                                                        preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    CMTime insertTime = kCMTimeZero;

    NSMutableArray *arrayInstructions = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    int i = 0;

    for (NSMutableDictionary * dict in self.arraySelectedAssets) {

            AVAsset *asset = [dict objectForKey:@"avasset"];

            //[self orientationForTrack:asset];

            AVAssetTrack* videoAssetTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
            AVAssetTrack* audioAssetTrack = [[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];

            [track insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration) ofTrack:videoAssetTrack atTime:insertTime error:nil];

            [audioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration) ofTrack:audioAssetTrack atTime:insertTime error:nil];

            AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *firstVideoCompositionInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
            // Set the time range of the first instruction to span the duration of the first video track.
            firstVideoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(insertTime, videoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration);


            AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* firstVideoLayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:[[asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]];
            CGAffineTransform translateToCenter = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( 0,-1334);
            CGAffineTransform rotateBy90Degrees = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( M_PI_2);
            CGAffineTransform shrinkWidth = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1); // needed because Apple does a "stretch" by default - really, we should find and undo apple's stretch - I suspect it'll be a CALayer defaultTransform, or UIView property causing this
            CGAffineTransform finalTransform = CGAffineTransformConcat( shrinkWidth, CGAffineTransformConcat(translateToCenter, rotateBy90Degrees) );
            [firstVideoLayerInstruction setTransform:finalTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];

            firstVideoCompositionInstruction.layerInstructions = @[firstVideoLayerInstruction];

            [arrayInstructions addObject:firstVideoCompositionInstruction];

        insertTime = CMTimeAdd(insertTime, videoAssetTrack.timeRange.duration);

        i = i + 1;

    }

    AVMutableVideoComposition *mutableVideoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
    mutableVideoComposition.instructions = arrayInstructions;
    mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(1334, 750);
    mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);


    // 4 - Get path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mergeVideo-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];
    self.combinedVideoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];

    // 5 - Create exporter

    self.timerExporter = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01f
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(exporterProgress)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];

    // 5 - Create exporter
    self.exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition
                                                                      presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    self.exporter .outputURL=self.combinedVideoURL;
    self.exporter .outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    self.exporter .shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    self.exporter.videoComposition = mutableVideoComposition;
    [self.exporter  exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

        [self.timerExporter invalidate];

        switch (self.exporter.status) {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"Export failed -> Reason: %@, User Info: %@",
                      self.exporter.error.localizedFailureReason,
                      self.exporter.error.userInfo.description);
                [self showError:self.exporter.error.localizedFailureReason];
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                NSLog(@"Export cancelled");
                break;

            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
                NSLog(@"Export finished");

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    self.labelProgressText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (100%%)", NSLocalizedString(@"Combining The Videos", nil)];
                    [self applyTheFilter];
                });

                break;

        }

    }];
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not the answer you're looking for, I'm afraid. I had the same problem transforming and exporting a single video - `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality` would work for some assets and not for others.

My guess at the time was that the assets that didn't work weren't of a high enough size/framerate/quality to render using `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality`.

As you did, I ended up using `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough`. In your case the end result will presumably be that all the assets you're splicing together will be rendered in their original format.

Comment: I am wondering if it has anything to do with where the videos were created from, for example if they were created on the device then they will work, if not some will fail.

Comment: That seems to match my experience - videos shot on an iPhone were OK, but ones downloaded from, say, WhatsApp would often seem to be the problematic ones.

Comment: Just tested the same videos using the Go Splice app and they seem to combine on that without any issues. I am wondering if it is something in my instead.

Comment: using AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough -> video down size it self